# Local notification after app restart

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

Suppose in my ios app a local notification is set to be send at 6 am tomorrow.After that my app becomes inactive and cleared from the memory by the ios kernerl. After that if I open the app 
1.at 5am tomorrow and uses it till 7 am .
2. at 6.30 am

Will the previously set notification be sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)**
If your app is active when a local notification is delivered the `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification` method will be called. But in such a situation no alert or notification sound will be there.

**2)**
In this case, the local notification will surely delivered. And alert will be displayed and sound will be played (According to modes).

Please check [**UILocalNotification**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Local notification will be sent if the app is closed or in the background. If I understand you correctly the app will be open at the time the notification should be sent. Answering your question, no, the notification won't display on screen. For those cases you should use `AlertView`.